# Likelihood ratio tests for quasi- models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, model-selection, likelihood, quasi-likelihood

I have been playing around with over-dispersion in binomial data and looking into qausi-binomial models as a solution. When comparing binomial models through the change in deviance, I can reproduce the p-value for the test-statistic using `pchi(deviance_change, df)`. However, in a similar quasi-binomial comparison where the change of deviance and df are the same, the p-value is different.

I vaguely understand that quasi-approaches don't strictly have likelihood functions, but could someone explain how the change in model deviance between two candidate models is being used in the Chi-squarred test?

An example is below.

```r
# some binomial data
x <- 1:5
yb1 <- matrix(c(4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 6, 5, 3, 2), ncol = 2)
```

```r
## binomial model
mb0 <- glm(yb1 ~ 1, family = binomial)
mb1 <- glm(yb1 ~ x, family = binomial)
anova(mb1, mb0, test='LRT')
```

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: yb1 ~ x
Model 2: yb1 ~ 1
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
1         3     0.5243                       
2         4     5.5842 -1  -5.0599  0.02449 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```r
## quasibinomial model
mqb0 <- glm(yb1 ~ 1, family = quasibinomial)
mqb1 <- glm(yb1 ~ x, family = quasibinomial)
anova(mqb1, mqb0, test='LRT')
```

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: yb1 ~ x
Model 2: yb1 ~ 1
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1         3     0.5243                          
2         4     5.5842 -1  -5.0599 8.325e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```